# set a global setting during django startup

Tags: django

[image]

The figure shows my django structure. I don't have a django app according to django glossary.

When django starts, I want to load a system configuration (I know how to run a Linux command) and save the result to a place where view.py can access. How would I implement it?

I tried the following options:

First, I looked at [Django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime%20discourages), but it discourages altering values in settings.py at runtime. Second, from what I understand, [Django Applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/) is saying I need to have a django app in order to use `AppConfig.ready()` which sets something global settings. Unless my folder structure is horribly wrong, I don't want to change it or switch to a django app.

I'm using django 3.1 on Linux.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want to do? Your question doesn't make it very clear on that... In case you want to read some environment variable, just do it in  `settings.py` and set it as a variable there.

Comment: I'm not as simply as reading a environment variable, but I need to run bash/Linux commands and get the output. But what you are saying makes sense. It looks like I can directly run the command in settings.py and set the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could alter django settings at runtime like this however it is discouraged.

```py
from django.conf import settings
settings.CUSTOM_KEY = True
```

Comment: If I use this approach, where do I write this code? Is there a `Application_Started` event?

Comment: you can edit your main/wsgi.py file to modify the value after the `get_wsgi_application()` call.